# Need help making custom batch file to apply icon to current folder via context menu

Tags: batch-file, automation, contextmenu

I'm new to automating computer tasks and creating batch scripts and I could use a little help. I do a lot of 3D modeling and texturing work and as such, assets have become a little bit ridiculous with me forgetting what I even named certain files. I've been creating icons for each folder from images of the models, but it takes hours to manually apply all of them having to go to properties/custom/ChangeIcon/browse meanwhile slowly succumbing to insanity. Is it possible to create a batch script where I right-click on an icon and press "apply icon to current folder"? Or maybe bulk select folders and run a program that finds icons in said folders and applies them to their respective folders. If it helps, the icons are already under the same name as the folders and are inside each folder.

Comment: Examples of code you've tried or scenarios to process are always good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV3QgDq2TGw

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this batch file ***[Customize_Icon_Folder.bat](https://pastebin.com/9ghxn9XQ)*** :

```bat
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Color 0A & Mode 78,5
set "ScriptName=%~nx0"
set /a "count=0"
Title Drag and Drop a folder or multi folders over "%ScriptName%"
if "%~1"=="" goto error
for %%a in (%*) do ( 
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "$Folder=" & pushd "%%~a" 2>nul && ( popd  & set "$Folder[!count!]=%%~a"
        ) || ( 
        set "$Folder="
        Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        color 0C & echo(
        echo    "%%~a"
        echo     ====^> is not a folder !
        echo     Exiting the script . . .
        endlocal
        Timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul & exit
    )
)
Rem Dispaly selected folders
Mode 75,10
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do (
    If [%count%] EQU [1] (
        echo You have chosen this folder : 
        echo [%%i] - "!$Folder[%%i]!"
    ) else (
        echo [%%i] - "!$Folder[%%i]!"
    )
)
Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul
Mode 78,8 & Cls & echo(
echo Please drag and drop your custom icon to be set to your folder over here
echo and press enter...
echo(
echo Or just write the whole path and press enter ...
Set /p "Icon="
If [!Icon!] EQU [] (
    cls & echo(
    echo  The selected icon is : "%systemroot%\system32\shell32.dll,47"
    Timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul
        for /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do (
            echo !$Folder[%%i]!
            Call :WriteDesktopIni !$Folder[%%i]! "%systemroot%\system32\shell32.dll,47"
        )
) Else (
        for %%a in (!Icon!) do ( set "Icon_Name=%%~nxa" & set "Ext=%%~xa" )
        If /I [!Ext!] EQU [.ICO] (
            cls & echo(
            echo The selected icon is : "!Icon_Name!"
            echo From this path : !Icon!
            Timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul
            for /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do (
                echo "!$Folder[%%i]!"
                Copy /y !Icon! "!$Folder[%%i]!\!Icon_Name!">nul 2>&1
                Attrib +H "!$Folder[%%i]!\!Icon_Name!">nul 2>&1
                Call :WriteDesktopIni !$Folder[%%i]! "!Icon_Name!"
            )
        ) else (
            Cls & Color 0C & echo( 
            echo The extension : [*!Ext!] is not allowed
            Timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul
        )
)
cls
echo(
echo  End of the script "%ScriptName%"
Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul & Exit
::***************************************************************************
:WriteDesktopIni [Folder] [Icon]
if exist "%~1\desktop.ini" ( attrib -h -s -a "%~1\desktop.ini" >nul 2>&1 )
(
    ECHO [.ShellClassInfo] 
    ECHO IconResource=%~2
)>"%~1\desktop.ini"
attrib +S +H +A "%~1\desktop.ini">nul 2>&1
attrib +R %~1>nul 2>&1
goto :eof
::***************************************************************************
:Error
Mode 86,10 & color 0B
echo( & echo(
echo   You should drag and drop a folder or multi folders over "%ScriptName%"
echo(
echo   Or Usage in command line like this syntax : 
echo(
echo   %~nx0 "FolderPath1" "FolderPath2" "FolderPath3" "FolderPath4"
Timeout /T 10 /nobreak>nul & exit
::***************************************************************************
```

Comment: It works sort of, I am trying to make a batch file to run this and feed it the current folder followed by the icon in the current folder that is under the same name. I just have a test folder for now but here's what i got: @echo off
cd C:\Users\user\Desktop
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cd') do (
     set foldername=%%~nxA
    )
start Customize_Icon_Folder.bat "TestFolder"
"%foldername%.ico" 
 
When I run it it grabs the correct folder then attempts to enter the icon but it says "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Desktop.ico" doesn't exist, yet when i type out the exact same path it works. Any Ideas?

Comment: @WEDimagineer You can also take a look at this [How can i show the change icon dialog box, with a vbscript or a command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1280759/how-can-i-show-the-change-icon-dialog-box-with-a-vbscript-or-a-command-line?answertab=active#tab-top)